# Rails 3 Observers and passing variables to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observers

I am integrating the MailChimp API into my app and am using a `UserObserver` to add the user to a MailChimp list on `after_create`, but I am having a slight problem with trying to update the user.

I allow the user to update their email address in the system which would be different in the MailChimp list, how could I pass the original email address to the `before_update` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it.

I set a new `attr_accessor` in my `UserModel`

```
attr_accessor :current_email
attr_accessible :current_email
```

And then in my Account Update Form, I set a hidden form field with the current_email

```
<%= f.hidden_field :current_email, :value => current_user.email %>
```

And the in my `UserObserver` I can access current_user with the user object being passed back.

```
  def after_update(user)
    ap user.current_email
  end
```

Hope this helps someone else